# Bootstrap 5 is not working after I using Select2 dropdown

Tags: css-selectors, dropdown, bootstrap-5, jquery-select2, option-type

The Select2 functionality is functioning correctly. However, there is an issue with Bootstrap, after using Select2, Bootstrap is not working anymore. I am using Bootstrap 5.3.[The picture show that the first select was using "Select2" and Bootstrap, second select only using Boostrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DzK8.png)

```
<!-- Bootstrap 5.3 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 5.3 -->

  <!-- Include jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  
  <!-- Include Select2 CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  
  <!-- Include Select2 JS after jQuery -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

```
<select id="selUser" class="form-select" name="Country" aria-label="Default select example">
<option selected>Country</option>
 <?php foreach ($data as $item): ?>
  <option value="<?= $item['country_name'] ?>"><?= $item['country_name'] ?>  </option>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selUser').select2();
});
</script>
```

[dropdown work fine. is only the css boostrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8G7G.png)

Comment: Try using `select2();`  instead of `select2{();`. You may also consider using bootstrap ver 5.3 `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: Hi, Raky. Yes I wrote select2(); in my code editor not select2{(); Just a typo in the StackOverflow. and The link that I added are <!-- Bootstrap 5.3 -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Ok. So is it working the way you wanted it to?

Comment: No~ Still the same the bootstrap is not working.

Comment: `.select2({theme: "bootstrap-5"});` help you?

Comment: It works. Thank Bro can refer to here https://apalfrey.github.io/select2-bootstrap-5-theme/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Update $data with your data recovery approach
$data = [
    ['country_name' => 'United States'],
    ['country_name' => 'Canada'],
    ['country_name' => 'United Kingdom'],
    // Add more countries here...
];
?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Select2 Example</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container mt-5">
      <label for="selUser" class="form-label">Select a Country:</label>
      <select id="selUser" class="form-select" name="Country" aria-label="Select a country">
        <option selected disabled>Select a country</option>
        <?php foreach ($data as $item): ?>
        <option value="<?= $item['country_name'] ?>">
          <?= $item['country_name'] ?>
        </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#selUser').select2();
      });
    </script>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Please try the above as suggested in Comments above

**Full Standalone Code**
This is a standalone Code. Copy-Paste in an independant `.htm` file and place it in your `localhost`folder for `php`and then try executin it.

```
<?php
// Update $data with your data recovery approach
$data = [
    ['country_name' => 'United States'],
    ['country_name' => 'Canada'],
    ['country_name' => 'United Kingdom'],
    // Add more countries here...
];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Select2 Example</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="container mt-5">
    <label for="selUser" class="form-label">Select a Country:</label>
    <select id="selUser" class="form-select" name="Country" aria-label="Select a country">
        <option selected disabled>Select a country</option>
        <?php foreach ($data as $item): ?>
        <option value="<?= $item['country_name'] ?>">
            <?= $item['country_name'] ?>
        </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selUser').select2();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    
    <select id="selUser" class="form-select" name="Country" aria-label="Default select example">
      <option selected>Country</option>
      <?php foreach ($data as $item): ?>
      <option value="<?= $item['country_name'] ?>">
        <?= $item['country_name'] ?>
      </option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#selUser').select2();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Not working sir